# VisualBasic - Reading Kinect skeleton joints values and assign to Label

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, label, kinect, kinect-sdk

I have to say, that I am very new to VisualBasic and VisualStudio (I am more comfortable with Java, android and web). I just found a good tutorial on how to do skeleton tracking with VB.

In my app, I have a picture box (left half of window), where the image and skeleton is displayed. On the other half, I have some Labels, where I want to display numeral values of skeletal joints.

I have managed to assign value from `shoulderright.X` to `Label2`, but it is not working all the time. It is actually working only the first time I run my app after building it. When I close and reopen my app again It shows "0" and stays like that.

Here is my code:

```
If skeletons.Length <> 0 Then

    For Each skel As Skeleton In skeletons

        'Right Arm
        Dim shoulderright As DepthImagePoint = kinz.MapSkeletonPointToDepth(skel.Joints(JointType.ShoulderRight).Position, DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30)
        Dim elbowright As DepthImagePoint = kinz.MapSkeletonPointToDepth(skel.Joints(JointType.ElbowRight).Position, DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30)
        Dim wristright As DepthImagePoint = kinz.MapSkeletonPointToDepth(skel.Joints(JointType.WristRight).Position, DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30)
        Dim handright As DepthImagePoint = kinz.MapSkeletonPointToDepth(skel.Joints(JointType.HandRight).Position, DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30)
        gfx.DrawLine(penz, New Point(shoulderright.X, shoulderright.Y), New Point(elbowright.X, elbowright.Y))
        gfx.DrawLine(penz, New Point(elbowright.X, elbowright.Y), New Point(wristright.X, wristright.Y))
        gfx.DrawLine(penz, New Point(wristright.X, wristright.Y), New Point(handright.X, handright.Y))

        Label2.Text = shoulderright.X.ToString()  //assigning the value to the Label
        Label2.Update()
```

Can anyone suggest me how to fix it? I have tried many variations like

```
Label2.Text = shoulderright.X.ToString
Label2.Update()
```

Or

```
Label2.Text = shoulderright.X.ToString()
```

Thank you.

Comment: I hate to be "that guy", but is there any specific reason you're using Visual Basic? The reason I ask is because if you're new to VB and Visual Studio and need to program for the Kinect, you may find yourself more comfortable using C#, which is more... actually very... similar to Java, a language you said you were comfortable with. There are also a few more tutorials about the Kinect written in C#.

Answer (score 0):

For each skeleton, you first zero out "shoulderright", get some value and then assign the value to the Label2.Text. This will overwrite the label each time you loop.

Try to make a textbox and for each skeleton make it: Textbox1.Text += shoulderright.X.ToString() & vbCrLf (lineshift)

This should make a list of every value in the loop.

Comment: What do you mean by  you first zero out "shoulderright"? Sorry for question like this, but like I said I am not very familiar with vb syntax

Comment: In your code, you zero the value for each loop, since you "Dim" it inside the loop. Then in the next loop the value is deleted and given a new number, which is also overwriting the last value assigned to Label2.Text.

So in your code, you basically only get to see the last shoulderright value.

Comment: So I am I right, that I have to initialize the shoulderright variable before the loop to 0 right? If so, I dont really know, how to do that. Am i supposed to put there shoulderright =0 ?And what is the type of that shoulderright?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, lets just use your code as is, but use a text box like I suggested instead. Make sure the text box property is set to multiline:

```
If skeletons.Length <> 0 Then

For Each skel As Skeleton In skeletons

    'Right Arm
    Dim shoulderright As DepthImagePoint = kinz.MapSkeletonPointToDepth(skel.Joints(JointType.ShoulderRight).Position, DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30)
    Dim elbowright As DepthImagePoint = kinz.MapSkeletonPointToDepth(skel.Joints(JointType.ElbowRight).Position, DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30)
    Dim wristright As DepthImagePoint = kinz.MapSkeletonPointToDepth(skel.Joints(JointType.WristRight).Position, DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30)
    Dim handright As DepthImagePoint = kinz.MapSkeletonPointToDepth(skel.Joints(JointType.HandRight).Position, DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30)
    gfx.DrawLine(penz, New Point(shoulderright.X, shoulderright.Y), New Point(elbowright.X, elbowright.Y))
    gfx.DrawLine(penz, New Point(elbowright.X, elbowright.Y), New Point(wristright.X, wristright.Y))
    gfx.DrawLine(penz, New Point(wristright.X, wristright.Y), New Point(handright.X, handright.Y))

    TextBox1.Text += shoulderright.X.ToString() & vbCrLf
Next
```

Can you now see all the values inside the text box?

Comment: Thanx, but it puts there a loooooooot of zeros so I cant even see the value